# NextJS Unable to use library using SASS and CSS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I'm trying to add wix-style-react plugin inside my NextJS project but I'm unable to build. Inside their [documentation](https://github.com/wix/wix-style-react), they say they use  Stylable, SASS and CSS Modules.

When I install the plugin and build, I get the following error :

> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
>   @import '../common';

I tried both following methods :

1. Using next-sass inside my `next.config.js`

```js
// next.config.js
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')

module.exports = withSass({
  cssModules: true
})
```

This way I got another error warning me about a .css file

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
>   .root {
>   |   display: inline-block;
>   |   text-overflow: ellipsis;

2. Using next-css in combination with next-sass

```js
// next.config.js
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')
const withCss = require('@zeit/next-css')

module.exports = withCss(
  withSass({
    cssModules: true,
  })
)
```

With this config, I get again the same error as with no config. I tried to follow [this](https://wix-style-react.now.sh/?selectedKind=Introduction&selectedStory=Usage%20Without%20Yoshi&full=0&addons=0&stories=1&panelRight=0) in order to configure my webpack. But I have an error `StylableWebpackPlugin is not a constructor`

### To Reproduce

1. Create a new blank project with `create-next-app`
2. Install the module `yarn add wix-style-react`
3. Build `yarn build`

### System information

- OS: macOS
- Version of Next.js: 9.1.4

Answer (score 1):

config

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
module.exports = withCSS({
    webpack: function(config) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "url-loader",
          options: {
            limit: 100000
            // name: '[name].[ext]'
          }
        }
      });
      return config;
    },
    ...withSass({
      cssModules: true,
      webpack: function(config) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
          use: {
            loader: "url-loader",
            options: {
              limit: 100000
              // name: '[name].[ext]'
            }
          }
        });
        return config;
      }
    }),
    cssModules: false
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned `StylableWebpackPlugin is not a constructor` can be fixed by importing the plugin like this:

`const { StylableWebpackPlugin} = require('@stylable/webpack-plugin');` but would this be enough to set up this library with Webpack? probably not. As their preferred bundler is Yoshi and their documentation isn't clear (outdated). However, they seem to be working on a Stylable loader for webpack (seen in one of their github branches). Hopefully, that would make a difference soon.